# Will the Heroku CLI work on Ubuntu 16.04 without Ruby?

Tags: 16.04

The Heroku CLI instructions for Ubuntu 16.04 tell you to ensure that Ruby is installed on your computer before installing (getting started with Python instructions).

Will the Heroku CLI work without Ruby? I don't want to install Ruby. :-)

Comment: Did you try? ;)

Comment: No.  I was just curious about it and thought there might be a someone out there who could give me a quick heads up. I installed Ruby anyways. It's not hurting anything.